# Unable to run threads concurrently

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, thread-sleep

**Synopsis** I am executing a simple program in which I instantiate and then detach 5 threads, the function I pass reads a video-stream, and writes a video-file.
The problem now is, that video files written have skipped too many frames.  I want all of these threads to run concurrently and generate video files from the streaming data WITHOUT skipping any frames.
**Question** How to prioritize these threads so that they are active at all times? 
**OS** **:** **Ubuntu  16.04**

```
void myfunction( string  stream, string video_name)
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap(stream);//read stream
    Mat frame;
    int frame_width = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    int frame_height = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

    VideoWriter video(video_name,CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D'),10, Size(frame_width,frame_height)); 

    while(1){ 
        cap >> frame; //capture frame
        video.write(frame); 
    }

}//end of myfunction

void main()
    {
        std::thread t1 (myfunction,my_stream_link, "myoutput1.avi");
        //t1.detach();
        std::thread t2 (myfunction,my_stream_link, "myoutput2.avi");
        //t2.detach();
        std::thread t3 (myfunction,my_stream_link, "myoutput3.avi");
        //t3.detach();
        std::thread t4 (myfunction,my_stream_link, "myoutput4.avi");
        //t4.detach();
        std::thread t5 (myfunction,my_stream_link, "myoutput5.avi");
        //t5.detach();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        t4.join();
        t5.join();

}//end of main
```

Comment: You can't set priorities for `std::thread`s. You also most likely want to `.join` instead of `.detach`. Also `void main` is not allowed in C++. Priority usually means regarding CPU, but you need IO priority. Look up a library that is able to do that.

Comment: I have tried `.join`. With `.join` a single thread is executed at a time. Am I missing something?

Comment: you should join them only in the end after starting all of them

Comment: `.join`ing the threads replaces your `while(1)` loop so instead of waiting infinitely you wait until all the threads are done. You can also start only 4 threads and run `myfunction(my_stream_link, "myoutput5.avi");` before `.join`ing so that you don't have a thread that doesn't do anything.

Comment: @nwp I didn't get your last point. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Please, indent the source code in your question.

Comment: If you start 5 threads that do work and then wait for them you have 6 threads total and the main thread just sits around waiting without doing anything useful. Instead you can start 4 threads only and give the work load of thread 5 to the main thread. That way all 5 threads are working and you don't have a useless thread. It's a micro-optimization, probably not even worth talking about.

Comment: Okay! 
As per your suggestion, I `.join`ed the threads. But only 3 threads are active. 2 of them were active at start but then became idle.

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and post **actual**, **updated** code that compiles. You have instantiated `t1` four times. You are running a busy loop in `main()` that probably hogs your entire CPU as well.

Comment: No, I've removed the loop after `.join` implementation.

Comment: How do you pass a C++ string to `VideoWriter()` when it expects a C-string? And how do you manage to use `frame` in your threads without declaring it?

Comment: I am not sure about difference between C++ or C-string.
I am declaring `Mat` object. I missed to add it here, sorry.

Comment: What is the value of `my_stream_link`? Where/what is the video coming from at what frame rate and what size? How are the cameras attached - network? USB 2.0? USB 3.0? CSI? How many CPU cores do you have and what spec?

Comment: `my_stream_link`'s values is an IP camera's stream.
Camera is at remote location. A constant 10 fps is what I get.
My CPU has 8 cores, 16 GB RAM. Intel® Core™ i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz × 8

Comment: And the image dimensions in pixels?

Comment: The image dimensions in pixels are 1280X720.

Comment: What's the FOURCC code of the input stream from the cameras?

Comment: Even if you get a bunch of threads writing frames fast enough, how do you intend to stitch them back together in the right order?

Comment: Mark Setchell, The FOURCC code is XVID. Video files are written into `.avi`

Comment: Why do you say *"camera"* and not *"cameras"*? I assume you have 5 cameras, surely? What happens if you change your code to just run 1 camera and then run 5 copies of the program in parallel so you are not multithreading - does it work then? What make/model are the cameras? If you just run one camera, what network bandwidth does it generate? What if you run 2 cameras?

Comment: Just a single camera, I am providing its stream to all five threads. Well, when I run 5 different instances, the run time libraries are loaded for each instance. Which in turns results into more memory consumption. 
And yes, it works perfectly fine. But memory consumption is the issue.